# Git: trailing whitespace causes file to remain in modified state

Tags: git, windows-7

I have a git repo. There are some files committed into it which already contain trailing white space. Now if I ever make a change to any such file and then try to discard it with `git checkout .`,  git undoes my changes alright, but the file still remains the modified state. No matter how many times I repeat `git checkout .` thereafter, the state does not change.

If I do a `git diff` at this point, it shows me that the whole file has changed, i.e. the full contents of the file have been replaced by new contents. Also doing a `git diff --check` (correctly) shows me the trailing whitespace errors that was originally present in the file.

The only way I can restore this file to unmodified state is by running `git rm . --cached && git reset --hard`, which is very awkward.

I understand that git is touchy about whitespace errors, but I do not expect the above behaviour from it. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? Is this a feature or a bug? Also, if it's normal behaviour, what's the best way to restore the file to unmodified state.

I'm running git version `1.8.3.msysgit.0` on `Windows7 x64`.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the all content doesn't change because of end of line conversion.

Do a:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

(It is set to true by default with msysgot)

Then try again your `git checkout .`.

---

The [OP Frederick The Fool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32688/frederick-the-fool) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911372/git-trailing-whitespace-causes-file-to-remain-in-modified-state/22911436#comment37480338_22911436):

> It did eventually turn out to be due to line endings. I thought I had dealt with the line-ending problems using the method [recommended here on GitHub](http://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).
>
> But turns out the problem wasn't fixed in all files.
>   So what I had to do was to:
>
> 1. arbitrarily modify all files in my repo.
> 2. Do a `git checkout .` at the root of the repo.
> 3. Since not all files would be undone by step 2, do a `git commit -a` on all of them.
>
> These steps got rid of the problem permanently.

Comment: Is it possible to do a single checkout with `autocrlf = false`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla "single" checkout? I just set that to false, and forget about it, making any subsequent checkout behaving correctly.

Comment: `core.autocrlf` is false in this repo, but we're using `* text=auto` in `.gitattributes` to achieve line ending normalization. Still normalization or not, git should undo the file when I run `checkout .`   and it's not doing that.

Comment: @FrederickTheFool it should undo, but on checkout, it would modify *all* files. I would recommend something more targeted than '*'.

Comment: VonC, `* text=auto` will not normalize _all_ files. It'll only do that for text files. And `* text=auto` is the recommended setting at a couple of places: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings   http://davidlaing.com/2012/09/19/customise-your-gitattributes-to-become-a-git-ninja/ So I think it's correct. The real problem I have is git not undoing files with whitespace errors.

Comment: @FrederickTheFool Ok. I was talking about eol because of the part mentioning "that the whole file has changed, i.e. the full contents of the file have been replaced by new content".

Comment: It was reasonable to think it's due to the line endings. But it apparently is not. I have no clue why this weird behaviour is occurring :(

Comment: Well, you were right. It did eventually turn out to be due to line endings. I thought I had dealt with the line-ending problems using the method recommended here: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings. But turns out the problem wasn't fixed in all files. So what I had to do was to: 1. arbitrarily modify all files in my repo. 2. Do a `git checkout .` at the root of the repo. 3. Since not all files would be undone by step 2, do a `git commit -a` on all of them. These steps got rid of the problem permanently.

Comment: @FrederickTheFool Great: I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.